# Remove event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We're currently working on a tv application. When you leave the home page the event listener should be removed because we need to add new control mapping. So on document ready, the right event listener should be added and on leaving this page the event listener should be removed.

Pressing the left key should get you to the first child of the div(this function already works).
The main problem is that whenever you go from one page to the next the event listener from the previous page controls do not get removed.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      Resultaat(e.keyCode);
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   window.document.removeEventListener("keydown", function() {
      Resultaat();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not removing the same function:

So we create a function `keydownHanlder` so that in `componentWillUnmount` we remove the same handler.

```
keydownHandler = (e) => {
   // handler code here
}

componentDidMount() {
    window.document.addEventListener('keydown', this.keydownHandler);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keydownHandler);
}
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems like the question has been asked before.